# Splitting field of $f=X^p -a \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Tags: galois-theory, roots-of-unity, splitting-field

Let $p$ be a prime number, and $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, a number such that there is no integer $k$ satisfying $p^k=a$. Write $f= X^p -a \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. I have to prove the following statements:

1. The degree of the splitting field $\Omega/\mathbb{Q}$ equals $p(p-1)$
2. Prove that the Galois group is isomorphic to the following:

$$
\{ 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
: \ a,b \in \mathbb{F}_p \ , \ a \neq 0\}
$$
*My own attempts*

1. I should see the extension as a double extension I guess. I thought I had to add some root $^p\sqrt{a}$ and a primitive root of unity $\zeta$. The first degree would $p$, and the second one would be $p-1$ because $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}X^k$ is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$. This would give the degree $p(p-1)$, right?
2. Every element $\sigma \in G$ has to map $\zeta$ to $\zeta^k$
   where $1\leq k \leq p-1$. The other root $\sqrt{a}$ has to be sent to some $^p\sqrt{a}^m$, where $1 \leq m \leq p$. 
   So I took the map.

$$
\phi : 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\longmapsto \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
      \zeta \quad \mapsto \quad \zeta^a\\
       ^p\sqrt{a} \quad \mapsto \quad ^p \sqrt{a} \cdot \zeta^b  
     \end{array}
   \right.$$
If we multiply to matrices we get:
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\cdot
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x & y \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
ax & ay+b \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
$$
The upper right corner troubles me. I don't see why it doesn't work componentwise. Could someone explain me?

$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of your map $\phi$ looks dubious to me. You have to map $\gamma=\sqrt[p]a$ to another root of $X^p-a$, and $\gamma^b$ just won't do. Since the set of roots of that polynomial is $\{\,\zeta^i\gamma\mid 0\leq i<p\,\}$, it would be more appropriate to choose $\zeta^b\gamma$ as its image. Then the image of an arbitrary root will be $\phi_{a,b}(\zeta^i\gamma)=\zeta^{ia+b}\gamma$. Moreover $\phi_{a,b}(\phi_{c,d}(\zeta^i\gamma))=\zeta^{(ic+d)a+b}\gamma = \zeta^{ica+da+b}\gamma$ which is beginning to look like matrix multiplication. Can you take it from here?